# How to find time duration of ride given its starting time and ending time by using sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: carpooling schema]

The start_on column in RIDE table is starting date and time for each ride and ends_on column is ending date and time of ride.
i have to fetch the ride whose travel duration is maximum i.e. [start_on - ends_on] is maximum for which ride.
the datediff function is not working in oracle platform.
please help with code that run on oracle.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: A good question should also provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Revision: As @JonHeller pointed out the ERD has timestamps rather than Dates. But nothing actually changes, except the description of the result. Timestamps can also be directly subtracted. The result being an [Interval](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-169DE9FB-36A5-4087-9857-7F03DCF8D3C6.htm). Intervals are dortable so a max interval can be determined. The base query remains the same - to get where the duration is maximum resolves to:

```
select ... , max(start_on - end_on) longest_duration ...
```

See revised example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=009dbda6ffc8227dfd46cb9a822b5627).

---

In Oracle dates can be directly subtracted, there is no need for datediff function. The result is a NUMBER with the whole number representing full days and the decimal part representing the fractional part of a day. It does not directly give time intervals; for example you might get 2.25 which would be 2 days 6 hours(6 hrs=1/4 day)  
In your case to get where the duration is maximum resolves to:

```
select ... , max(start_on - end_on) longest_duration ...
```

See Example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=63eb05151df90bf33c4db6daf5251ed3).

Comment: Part of their difficulty might be because the columns are TIMESTAMPs instead of DATEs. Subtracting the columns will return an interval instead of a number.

Comment: OOPS I missed that, Thanks @JonHeller. I revised the answer to show timestamps instead.

Answer (score 0):

Extract (hour from ends_on-start_on) <1